# Delete AWS RDS S3 Exported Snapshots

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rds

So I have created S3 Exports from existing snapshots in RDS. I would like to delete duplicated ones. But I don't see any button to delete them.

I have already deleted the files from the bucket. But the entry still shows up.

Any idea how to delete them?

[image: s3]

Comment: I have the same problem, and so does [this person](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/gb177q/rds_export_to_s3/). Also haven't found anything in the docs about this feature or when it's going to be available.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...looks like there's a CLI that will do it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lexv2-models/delete-export.html

...well, this may be only for the Lex service.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/545237)

Comment: After trying to use the delete CLI. This link seems not to be the solution for deleting RDS exported snapshots on S3.